# Looping through object to create multiple string values

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to work out how to write some logic to solve a problem, a client wants to pass their entire data object into to a single variable. I have worked out how to do this however I am a very notice coder and therefore struggling to write the code.

I managed to find this code, which gets half of what I need:

```
for (var prop in mi) {
  if (mi.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
     console.log("key: " + prop + " value: " + mi[prop])
  }
}
```

Output:

```
key: 076 value: value1
key: 072 value: value2
```

What I am struggling to do is everytime this loops through I want to build a single variable, that is a series of ',' separate strings of the value pairs. to create the following output:

```
var x = "key: 076 value: value1", "key: 072 value: value2";
```

I dont want to turn it into a single string, as I need to pass a comma separated list of strings into one variable.

Comment: do you need a single string, or an array of strings?

Comment: Why you need to do that? I mean, converting the data in that way. If you do so it would be very difficult to get the key and value.If you want to join all the data to a single variable the best way is to make it a JSON.

Comment: Perhaps I'm unclear on what you're asking.. Can you store the data into an array: x = ["key: 076 value: value1", "key: 072 value: value2"] ?  If so, you could `push`  each key/value string into the array at each pass of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put everything in an Array and then join it with ", ":

```js
mi = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}
ar = [];
for (var prop in mi) {
  if (mi.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
     ar.push("key: " + prop + " value: " + mi[prop])
  }
}
console.log(ar.join(", "));
```

Or a one-liner if you prefer:

```js
mi = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}

out = Object.keys(mi).reduce((all, item) => {all.push("key: " + item + " value: " + mi[item]); return all}, []).join(", ");
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Is there a way that while looping through of checking the value length and only if the value is greater than 0, push?

Comment: Did you try it? You have an `if` there in the code, just add another condition to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all your data into a variable the best way to do it is creating a JSON that will have all the required data.

```js
var data1 = ["asdf",1,345,"asdf1qwer56"];
var data2 = "username";
var data3 = 12;
var dataN = new Date();

var allData = {
  someVariables : data1,
  userName : data2,
  someNumber : data3,
  userDate: dataN
}

console.log("accessing all the data",allData);
console.log("accessing a specific data",allData.someVariables);
```

If you need that this data be converted to string you can also use 
`JSON.stringify` so it will convert the variable into a string, and then you can convert it again to an Object by using `JSON.parse`